# Example code for testing the filesystem in Golang

Tags: unit-testing, go

I'm trying to write a unit test for a function that will interact with the filesystem and I'd like to be able to mock the filesystem during testing.

The code below was given as the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16742331/how-to-mock-abstract-filesystem-in-go) question, where you would create a filesystem interface to use during testing, but I'm new to Go and am struggling to figure out how to use it.

Would someone be able to provide an example of how this interface would be used in a test please?

```
var fs fileSystem = osFS{}

type fileSystem interface {
    Open(name string) (file, error)
    Stat(name string) (os.FileInfo, error)
}

type file interface {
    io.Closer
    io.Reader
    io.ReaderAt
    io.Seeker
    Stat() (os.FileInfo, error)
}

// osFS implements fileSystem using the local disk.
type osFS struct{}

func (osFS) Open(name string) (file, error)        { return os.Open(name) }
func (osFS) Stat(name string) (os.FileInfo, error) { return os.Stat(name) }
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One important thing you must not forget: you can only mock the file system if the code that interacts with the file system does so via the above presented file system interface (`filesystem`), using the `fs` global variable (or some other `filesystem` value that the test code can change, e.g. a passed `fs` parameter).

Let's see such an example function:

```
func getSize(name string) (int64, error) {
    stat, err := fs.Stat(name)
    if err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }
    return stat.Size(), nil
}
```

This simple `getSize()` function returns the size of a file specified by its name, returning the error if `filesystem.Stat()` fails (returns an error).

And now let's write some unit tests that fully cover this `getSize()` function.

### What we will need

We need a mocked version of `filesystem`, mocked so that it does not actually interact with the filesystem, but returns sensible data when methods of `filesystem` are called (`filesystem.Stat()` in our case). To easiest mock `filesystem` (or any interface), we will embed `filesystem` in our `mockedFS`, so we "inherit" all its methods, and we will only need to mock what is actually used by the testable code. Note that calling other methods would result in runtime panic, as we won't really give a sensible, non-`nil` value to this embedded `filesystem`, but for the sake of tests it is not needed.

Since `filesystem` returns a value of [`os.FileInfo`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#FileInfo) (besides an error), which is an interface (and its implementation is not exported from the [`os`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/) package), we will also need to mock `os.FileInfo`. This will be `mockedFileInfo`, and we will do it very similarly to mocking `filesystem`: we'll embed the interface type `os.FileInfo`, so actually we'll only need to implement `FileInfo.Size()`, because that is the only method called by the testable `getSize()` function.

### Preparing / Setting up the mocked filesystem

Once we have the mocked types, we have to set them up. Since `getSize()` uses the global `fs` variable to interact with the filesystem, we need to assign a value of our `mockedFS` to this global `fs` variable. Before doing so it's recommended to save its old value, and properly restore the old value once we're done with the test: "cleanup".

Since we fully want to test `getSize()` (including the error case), we armour our `mockedFS` with the ability to control whether it should return an error, and also the ability to tell it what to return in case we don't want any errors.

When doing the tests, we can manipulate the "state" of the `mockedFS` to bend its behavior to our needs.

### And the test(ing) code

Without further ado, the full testing code:

```
type mockedFS struct {
    // Embed so we only need to "override" what is used by testable functions
    osFS

    reportErr  bool  // Tells if this mocked FS should return error in our tests
    reportSize int64 // Tells what size should Stat() report in our test
}

type mockedFileInfo struct {
    // Embed this so we only need to add methods used by testable functions
    os.FileInfo
    size int64
}

func (m mockedFileInfo) Size() int64 { return m.size }

func (m mockedFS) Stat(name string) (os.FileInfo, error) {
    if m.reportErr {
        return nil, os.ErrNotExist
    }
    return mockedFileInfo{size: m.reportSize}, nil
}

func TestGetSize(t *testing.T) {
    oldFs := fs
    // Create and "install" mocked fs:
    mfs := &mockedFS{}
    fs = mfs
    // Make sure fs is restored after this test:
    defer func() {
        fs = oldFs
    }()

    // Test when filesystem.Stat() reports error:
    mfs.reportErr = true
    if _, err := getSize("hello.go"); err == nil {
        t.Error("Expected error, but err is nil!")
    }

    // Test when no error and size is returned:
    mfs.reportErr = false
    mfs.reportSize = 123
    if size, err := getSize("hello.go"); err != nil {
        t.Errorf("Expected no error, got: %v", err)
    } else if size != 123 {
        t.Errorf("Expected size %d, got: %d", 123, size)
    }
}
```

Comment: This is for file stat, but how would it be for openFile?

Comment: @PritiBiyani This example shows how to mock `filesystem.Stat()` which returns an interface value (`os.FileInfo`). You are asking how to mock `filesystem.Open()` which also returns an interface value (`file`). So the answer is: in the same way, but obviously you have to "override" `filesystem.Open()` instead of `filesytem.Stat()`, and obviously you have to create and return a `mockedFile` instead of `mockedFileInfo`.

Comment: Ah. Thanks. How would be my initialization in production code?
What would be my original `fs` ?

Comment: @PritiBiyani The original `fs` is in the linked question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16742331/how-to-mock-abstract-filesystem-in-go

Comment: @PritiBiyani Please read the link I posted. The answer is there.

Comment: [A (bad) attempt at doing the open mocking…](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63992279/232794) Yes, I am struggling with it.

Answer (score 9):

Another option is the `testing/fstest` package:

```
package main
import "testing/fstest"

func main() {
   m := fstest.MapFS{
      "hello.txt": {
         Data: []byte("hello, world"),
      },
   }
   b, e := m.ReadFile("hello.txt")
   if e != nil {
      panic(e)
   }
   println(string(b) == "hello, world")
}
```

https://golang.org/pkg/testing/fstest