# how to test method that prints to console in golang?

Tags: unit-testing, go

I have next struct.

```
package logger

import "fmt"

type IPrinter interface {
    Print(value string)
}

type ConsolePrinter struct{}

func (cp *ConsolePrinter) Print(value string) {
    fmt.Printf("this is value: %s", value)
}
```

Test coverage says I need to test that ConsolePrinter Print method.

How can I cover this method?

Thanks.

Comment: Use the same principle as in this answer: [Fill os.Stdin for function that reads from it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46365221/fill-os-stdin-for-function-that-reads-from-it/46365584#46365584).

Comment: @icza Thanks, I've followed your instructions, I am adding answer below.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Following comment that @icza wrote, I've written the test below.

```
func TestPrint(t *testing.T) {
    rescueStdout := os.Stdout
    r, w, _ := os.Pipe()
    os.Stdout = w

    cp := &ConsolePrinter{}
    cp.Print("test")

    w.Close()
    out, _ := io.ReadAll(r)
    os.Stdout = rescueStdout

    if string(out) != "this is value: test" {
        t.Errorf("Expected %s, got %s", "this is value: test", out)
    }
}
```

I've found example in question [What is the best way to convert byte array to string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10473800/in-go-how-do-i-capture-stdout-of-a-function-into-a-string).

Answer (score 12):

Use [`Examples`](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#hdr-Examples) to convey the usage of a function.

Don't fret over 100% test coverage, especially for simple straightforward functions.

```
func ExampleHello() {
    fmt.Println("hello")
    // Output: hello
}
```

The additional benefit is that `examples` are outputted in a generated doc with go doc tool.

Comment: If I understood well, I would have to call ConsolePrinter Print method in example, right?

Comment: Just try don't delibarate :)

Comment: So now you know, but you've got a documented and tested piece of code. Remember, that a cover is only a software metric. There is no need to duplicate tests to get a cover higher.

Comment: I understand what you say. Still, I wanted to see if there was way for that part of code to be covered with tests.

Comment: by your opinion, which is better, example as you wrote or test?

Comment: For example - "when you want to document a function to the user, use Examples. Otherwise use tests - often you need to use data provider to test the function. It's all relative. Make your choice.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to create new instance of the [logger](https://golang.org/pkg/log/#New), which would behave exactly as `fmt` methods for printing data to console. Also, you can configure it with additional features like showing the filename, date and etc. Such custom logger can be passed as a parameter to your service/instance factory method. That would make it really easy to mock and test.

Your code

```
type Logs interface {
    Println(v ...interface{})
}

type InstanceToTest struct {
    log Logs
}

func InstanceToTestFactory(logger Logs) *InstanceToTest {
    return &InstanceToTest{logger}
}

func (i *InstanceToTest) SomeMethod(a string) {
    i.log.Println(a)
}
```

Create a mock for logger

```
type LoggerMock struct {
    CalledPrintln []interface{}    
}

func (l *LoggerMock) Println(v ...interface{}) {
    l.CalledPrintln = append(CalledPrintln, v)
}
```

And in your test

```
func TestInstanceToTestSomeMethod(t *testing.T) {
    l := &LoggerMock{}
    i := InstanceToTestFactory(l)
    a := "Test"

    i.SomeMethod(a)

    if len(l.CalledPrintln) == 0 || l.CalledPrintln[0] != a {
        t.Error("Not called")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I am doing this for other method I am testing.