# How do I unit test this promptui package written in golang?

Tags: unit-testing, go, command-prompt

I am new to golang and I am using an interactive prompt called promptui (https://github.com/manifoldco/promptui) in a project of mine. I have written several unit tests for this project already but I am struggling with how I would unit test this particular package that requires an input.

For example, How would I go about testing the following lines of code (encapsulated in a function):

```
func setEmail() string {
  prompt := promptui.Prompt{Label: "Input your Email",
     Validate: emailValidations,
  }

  email, err := prompt.Run()
  if err != nil {
    color.red("failed getting email")
    os.exit(3)
  }
  return email
}
```

I think I need to somehow mock stdin but can't figure out the best way to do that within a test.

Comment: Why would you unit test an external package? It should have its own tests already.

Comment: Well I want to test my function that uses that package.

Comment: Your function that uses it doesn't do anything itself, unit testing it delivers no value.

Comment: It returns the email string.  The function is used a few times throughout.  I guess I could just reuse the same promptui code block throughout but thought that would go against DRY best practices.

Comment: I agree that there is a value in testing code that calls `promptui`. Tests create a `safety net` that reduce regression errors. You never know how you have to refactor/extend that code in the future.

Answer (score 4):

You should not try to test `promptui` as it is expected to be tested by its author.

What you can test:

1. You send correct parameters when you create `promptui.Prompt`
2. You use that `promptui.Prompt` in your code
3. You properly handle `promptui.Prompt` results

As you can see, all these tests does not verify if `promptui.Prompt` works correctly inside.

Tests #2 and #3 could be combined. You need to run you code against mock and if you got correct result, you can believe that both #2 and #3 are correct.

Create mock:

```
type Runner interface {
    Run() (int, string, error)
}

type promptMock struct {
    // t is not required for this test, but it is would be helpful to assert input parameters if we have it in Run()
    t *testing.T
}

func (p promptMock) Run() (int, string, error) {
    // return expected result
    return 1, "", nil
}
```

You will need separate mock for testing error flow.

Update your code to inject mock:

```
func setEmail(runner Runner) string {
    email, err := runner.Run()
    if err != nil {
      color.red("failed getting email")
      os.exit(3)
    }
    return email
}
```

Now it is testable.

Create function that creates `prompt`:

```
func getRunner() promptui.Prompt {
  return promptui.Prompt{Label: "Input your Email",
     Validate: emailValidations,
  }
}
```

Write simple assert test to verify that we create correct structure.

The only not tested line will be `setEmail(getRunner())` but it is trivial and can be covered by other types of tests.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

For whatever reason, they don't export their `stdin` interface (https://github.com/manifoldco/promptui/blob/master/prompt.go#L49), so you can't mock it out, but you can directly mock `os.Stdin` and prefill it with whatever you need for testing. Though I agree with @Adrian, it has its own tests, so this shouldn't be necessary.

Extracted and refactored/simplified from source: [Fill os.Stdin for function that reads from it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46365221/fill-os-stdin-for-function-that-reads-from-it)

Refactored this way, it can be used for any function that reads from `os.Stdin` and expects a specific string.

Playground link: https://play.golang.org/p/rjgcGIaftBK

```
func TestSetEmail(t *testing.T) {
    if err := TestExpectedStdinFunc("email@test.com", setEmail); err != nil {
        t.Error(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println("success")
}

func TestExpectedStdinFunc(expected string, f func() string) error {
    content := []byte(expected)
    tmpfile, err := ioutil.TempFile("", "example")
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    defer os.Remove(tmpfile.Name()) // clean up

    if _, err := tmpfile.Write(content); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    if _, err := tmpfile.Seek(0, 0); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    oldStdin := os.Stdin
    defer func() { os.Stdin = oldStdin }() // Restore original Stdin

    os.Stdin = tmpfile
    actual := f()
    if actual != expected {
        return errors.New(fmt.Sprintf("test failed, exptected: %s actual: %s", expected, actual))
    }

    if err := tmpfile.Close(); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

promptui now has the Stdin property.

There is a fiddle here: https://play.golang.org/p/-mSgjY2kAw-

Here is our function that we will be testing:

```
func mock(p promptui.Prompt) string {
    p.Label = "[Y/N]"
    user_input, err := p.Run()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Prompt failed %v\n", err)
    }

    return user_input
}
```

We need to create `p`, which will be an instance of promptui.Prompt and have a custom Stdin.

I got some help here - https://groups.google.com/g/golang-nuts/c/J-Y4LtdGNSw?pli=1 - in how to make a custom Stdin value, which simply has to conform to io.ReadCloser.

```
type ClosingBuffer struct {
    *bytes.Buffer
}

func (cb ClosingBuffer) Close() error {
    return nil
}
```

And then you use that as Stdin in the reader:

```
func TestMock(t *testing.T) {

    reader := ClosingBuffer{
        bytes.NewBufferString("N\n"),
    }

    p := promptui.Prompt{
        Stdin: reader,
    }

    response := mock(p)

    if !strings.EqualFold(response, "N") {
        t.Errorf("nope!")
    }
    //t.Errorf(response)
}
```

---

edit: **The above doesn't work for multiple prompts within the same function**, as discussed here with a solution: https://github.com/manifoldco/promptui/issues/63 - "promptui internally uses a buffer of 4096 bytes. This means that you must pad your buffer or promptui will raise EOF."

I took this `pad()` function from that exchange - https://github.com/sandokandias/capiroto/blob/master/cmd/capiroto/main.go:

```
func pad(siz int, buf *bytes.Buffer) {
    pu := make([]byte, 4096-siz)
    for i := 0; i < 4096-siz; i++ {
        pu[i] = 97
    }
    buf.Write(pu)
}
```

Then the test - - this solution uses ioutil.NopCloser rather than creating a new struct:

```
func TestMock(t *testing.T) {

    i1 := "N\n"
    i2 := "Y\n"

    b := bytes.NewBuffer([]byte(i1))
    pad(len(i1), b)
    reader := ioutil.NopCloser(
        b,
    )
    b.WriteString(i2)
    pad(len(i2), b)

    p := promptui.Prompt{
        Stdin: reader,
    }

    response := mock(p)

    if !strings.EqualFold(response, "NY") {
        t.Errorf("nope!")
        t.Errorf(response)
    }
}
```

and the function we are testing:

```
func mock(p promptui.Prompt) string {
    p.Label = "[Y/N]"
    user_input, err := p.Run()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Prompt failed %v\n", err)
    }
    user_input2, err := p.Run()

    return user_input + user_input2
}
```

The fiddle for multiple prompts is here: https://play.golang.org/p/ElPysYq8aM1