# Need to generate runtime binary encoded file in golang

Tags: file, go, encode

I am working on the project in which I need to generate a file as binary encoded(bytes). Thing is that, I don't want to store the file but just need the encoded data to verify with some test data.

Here is the sample code I have [zip file](https://play.golang.org/p/FKA_9fT3Nvv)

Above example is for `zip` but I am not restricted to use `zip` or any file type. And here we need to have stored file to read but I don't want to store and delete the file later.

I know it has not much efforts to ask for the help, but as an newbie, I come to that only.

Thanks.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to create and how you want to use it. In general, you can just use an in-memory buffer, be it a simple `[]byte` or a `bytes.Buffer` which implements `io.Reader` and `io.Writer`, so you can use it to read and write just like a file.

Comment: Actually I have scenario like `test cases`, where I need a dummy encoded bytes of File(but don't want to create it) and need to check with other data. Otherwise I have to create a file and then perform the operation, but I don't have definite scenario to delete it(though I can't keep it )

Comment: You should change the use cases to not rely on the concrete `os.File` type but use interfaces instead (`io.Reader`, `io.Writer` and similar). That way no matter if you pass a `*bytes.Buffer` or an `*os.File`, it will work with both.

Comment: @icza You wants me to change the functionality? 
Considered it as test cases then how we can generate the bytes of virtual file?

Answer (score 3):

A better practice is to not rely on concrete types (e.g. [`os.File`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#File)), but use interfaces instead that describe the functionality you want to use the file for.

E.g. if you have a function that takes a file because it wants to read from it, use [`io.Reader`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader) instead:

```
func process(r io.Reader) error {
    // ...
}
```

Similarly, if you want to write to the file, use [`io.Writer`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Writer), or if you want to do  both, use [`io.ReadWriter`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#ReadWriter) or [`io.ReadWriteCloser`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#ReadWriteCloser). You may pass an `*os.File` value to these functions, because `*os.File` implements those interfaces.

The benefit of this is that you can call these functions with any values that implement the interface. If you want to test these functions, you may pass an in-memory [`bytes.Buffer`](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Buffer) which implements `io.Reader` and `io.Writer`, and whose content you can construct manually, at runtime, for example:

```
buf := &bytes.Buffer{}
buf.Write([]byte{1, 2, 3})
buf.WriteString("Hello")
```

Here `buf` will contain the bytes `1`, `2`, `3` and the string `"Hello"`. After that you may pass `buf` where a reader or writer is needed, e.g.:

```
process(buf)
```

See similar / related questions and examples:

[Fill os.Stdin for function that reads from it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46365221/fill-os-stdin-for-function-that-reads-from-it/46365584#46365584)

[Example code for testing the filesystem in Golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43912124/example-code-for-testing-the-filesystem-in-golang/43914455#43914455)