# Mocking open in go…

Tags: go

I have been following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43914455/232794) trying to mock open. I have got exactly no where.

This is the test code I have:

```
func (m mockedFS) Open(name string) (file, error) {
    if m.reportErrOpen {
        return nil, errors.New("Fake failure")
    }
    mockedFile := mockIORead{}
    mockedFile.On("ReadAll", mock.AnythingOfType("[]uint8")).Return(0, fmt.Errorf("error reading"))
    mockedFile.On("Read", mock.AnythingOfType("[]byte")).Return(0, errors.New("NON"))
    return mockedFile, nil
}

type mockIORead struct {
    mock.Mock
    reportErr  bool  // Tells if this mocked FS should return error in our tests
    reportSize int64 // Tells what size should Stat() report in our test
}

func (m mockIORead) Read(b []byte) (n int, err error) {
    if m.reportErr {
        return 0, errors.New("A fake failure")
    }
    s := "Fear the old blood"
    copy(b[:], s)
    return 0, nil
}

func (m mockIORead) Close() error {
    return nil
}

func (m mockIORead) ReadAt([]byte, int64) (int, error) {
    return 0, nil
}

func (m mockIORead) Seek(int64, int) (int64, error) {
    return 0, nil
}

func (m mockIORead) Stat() (os.FileInfo, error) {
    if m.reportErr {
        return nil, os.ErrNotExist
    }
    return mockedFileInfo{size: m.reportSize}, nil
}

func TestOok(t *testing.T) {
    oldFs := fs
    // Create and "install" mocked fs:
    mfs := &mockedFS{}
    fs = mfs
    // Make sure fs is restored after this test:
    defer func() {
        fs = oldFs
    }()
    mfs.reportErr = false
    mfs.reportErrOpen = false
    token, err := Ook("fake")
    assert.NotNil(t, err)
    assert.Equal(t, "Fear the old blood", token)
}
```

And this is the code under test:

```
func Ook(name string) (string, error) {

    _, err := fs.Stat(name)
    if err != nil {
        return "", nil
    }

    file, err := fs.Open(name)
    if err != nil {
        return "", errors.Wrap(err, "Cannot open token file")
    }
    defer file.Close()

    _, err = ioutil.ReadAll(file)
    fmt.Print("PING\n")
    if err != nil {
        return "", errors.Wrap(err, "Could not read token")
    }
    return "Fear the old blood", nil
    //return string(token), nil
}
```

***What the hell am I doing wrong?***

Comment: "What the hell am I doing wrong?" Probably not the answer you are looking for but the main problem is that you try to mock the filesystem at all. If your test really run on a machine _without_ _filesystem_ this is a necessary thing to do but it is also _really_ uncommon. Just read  from the fs. This is fine, even in tests. No need to mock everything. (You do not mock RAM and CPU either).

Comment: What is `fs` you use in your `Ook()` function? Also `mockIORead.Read()` must return the number of read bytes, the number returned by `copy()`!

Comment: @icza The same one used in your [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43914455/232794).

Answer (score 2):

The first error is that your `mockIORead.Read()` returns wrong values. It must return the number of read bytes (bytes written to the slice argument) (e.g. what `copy()` would return).

Next, `mockIORead.Read()` must be stateful! `Reader.Read()` might be called several times, there is no guarantee the passed slice can accommodate all the data you want to return (via the passed `b` slice).

So `mockIORead` must store the data you want to return, and it must remember how much of them has been delivered so far, so the next `Read()` call can continue from there.

An easy implementation of this is to utilize [`bytes.Buffer`](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Buffer):

```
type mockIORead struct {
    mock.Mock
    reportErr  bool  // Tells if this mocked FS should return error in our tests
    reportSize int64 // Tells what size should Stat() report in our test

    content *bytes.Buffer
}
```

When returning such a `mockIORead`, initialize `content` with the content you wish to return:

```
func (m mockedFS) Open(name string) (file, error) {
    if m.reportErrOpen {
        return nil, errors.New("Fake failure")
    }
    mockedFile := mockIORead{
        content: bytes.NewBufferString("Fear the old blood"),
    }

    return mockedFile, nil
}
```

And thanks to the available [`bytes.Buffer.Read()`](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Buffer.Read) method, the `mockIORead.Read()` implementation can be as simple as this:

```
func (m mockIORead) Read(b []byte) (n int, err error) {
    if m.reportErr {
        return 0, errors.New("A fake failure")
    }
    return m.content.Read(b)
}
```

The `Ook()` function itself should not try to "stat" as you haven't mocked it (and so calling the original `os.Stat()` will likely yield an error for the `"fake"` file name used in the test):

```
func Ook(name string) (string, error) {
    file, err := fs.Open(name)
    if err != nil {
        return "", errors.Wrap(err, "Cannot open token file")
    }
    defer file.Close()

    token, err := ioutil.ReadAll(file)
    fmt.Print("PING\n")
    if err != nil {
        return "", errors.Wrap(err, "Could not read token")
    }
    return string(token), nil
}
```

And the testing code:

```
func TestOok(t *testing.T) {
    oldFs := fs
    // Create and "install" mocked fs:
    mfs := &mockedFS{}
    fs = mfs
    // Make sure fs is restored after this test:
    defer func() {
        fs = oldFs
    }()

    mfs.reportErr = false
    mfs.reportErrOpen = false
    token, err := Ook("fake")
    assert.Nil(t, err)
    assert.Equal(t, "Fear the old blood", token)
}
```

Which yields a successful ("OK") test.

Comment: Thank you! That is not only clear but is useful as well. :+1: